# How to set project full name in Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

In Maven, the project name and the artifact name are different fields. `name` represents "the full name of the project" (according to the [Maven schema 4.0.0](https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd)), and the `artifactId` means the "identifier for this artifact that is unique within the group".

If I understand correctly, Gradle's `rootProject.name` is the equivalent of artifact ID, but what's the equivalent of a full project name?

#### Maven Publish plugin

I did some digging for the problem directly and have found exactly nothing.
I dug even more and found that the Maven Publish plugin [provides](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:modifying_the_generated_pom) an ability to set the name of the full name of the generated POM file.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            pom {
                name = 'My Library'
                description = 'A concise description of my library'
                url = 'http://www.example.com/library'
<...>
```

However, the question is if the Gradle itself has the property of equivalent meaning.